# Elapsed event v Tick event?

Tags: c#, timer

Is the Elapsed event of System.Timers.Timer effectively the same as the Tick event of System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

In specific circumstances are there advantages of using one rather than the other?

Comment: The `System.Threading.Timer` is the only one that worked for me in `Windows Server 2008 R2` though Timers.Timer worked in my `Windows 7 laptop`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check these links [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) and [here](http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/05/systemwindowsformstimer-vs.html) for complete understanding of timers in .Net framework.

There are three types of timers.

- System.Windows.Forms.Timer
- System.Timers.Timer
- System.Threading.Timer

I personally prefers `System.Timers.Timer` as it's thread-safe.

Comment: as I'm a newbie I need to ask why are the other's thread-unsafe?

Comment: @whytheq Thread-safe means that the instances of System.Timers.Timer class can be safely accessed from multiple threads. Other Timer classes will face issues in this case. Thread safety is a common problem in multithreaded applications. For complete understanding read this series of articles. http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: so in laymens terms the timer keeps running irrespective of what other threads are running?

Answer (score 12):

The other answers provide a lot of detail, but the overriding difference between the two timers you mentioned is that the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will invoke the callback on the UI thread, whereas the `System.Timers.Timer` will use one of the threads from the core thread pool.

Comment: That is a great way of saying it.

Comment: ...so `System.Timers.Timer` is thread-safe whereas the forms timer is not? And if I wish to run parallel processes using a timer to start each process then `System.Timers.Timer` is the best timer to use?

Comment: It depends on your threading requirements. If the code that the timer is executing needs to modify the GUI, then use the Forms timer.  Also, Given that there's (usually) only one event thread, it means that the Forms timer event handler will never be called concurrently (multiple times at the same time).  However, you generally should not be doing non-GUI related tasks on the GUI thread (as it makes the GUI less responsive) so the Timers timer would be better, with the caveat that you are now responsible for handling concurrency.